# Question about NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, initialization, nsmutablearray

I currently try to fill and NSMutableArray with something like this:

```
deck = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:52]; 
for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
  for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
    ANormalCard *card = [[ANormalCard alloc] initWithSuit:suit value:value];
    [deck addObject:card];
    [card autorelease];
  }
}
```

Now the problem is when I go over the array, only the last object I create is 52x in the array. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

---

**Edit:**

the -initWithSuit looks like this:

```
- (id) initWithSuit:(int)suit value:(int)val {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        theSuit = suit;
        theValue = val;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm using `NSEnumerator * enumerator = [deck objectEnumerator];` and a while loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: make sure that initWithSuit:value: is not returning always the same object.

Comment: I don't think I understood the question - what is the problem with the last object?

Comment: That code looks fine. How does your actual code differ? And can you post the code for initWithSuit:value: ?

Comment: At this point, I don't think the question is answerable without seeing the complete source code. Can you create a minimal version that still exhibits the behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet looks perfectly fine. The problem is likely in your `-initWithSuit:value:` method — I'd check whether you're accidentally initializing the cards incorrectly.

---

**Edit:** The init method just posted by the asker looks fine as well. What is the exact output you're seeing that leads you to believe that only the last object has been added 52 times? How exactly are you examining the array? (Your comment says you're using an NSEnumerator, but can you edit your question to include the snippet you're using for that?

Comment: the -initWithSuit looks like this :

-(id)initWithSuit:(int) suit value:(int)val
{
if ((self=[super init]) ) 
{
 theSuit = suit;
 theValue = val;
}
return self;
}